# How to send result after executing all queries

Tags: node.js, async.js

I've got following code

```
var data=[];
var i = 0,
    j = 9;

async.whilst(function () {
    return i <= j;
}, function (next) {
    connection.query('select * from table', function (err,rows, field) {
        data.push(rows.length);
        console.log(data);
    });

    i++;

    next();
}, function (err) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I want to execute the query first and then return result. How should I do it. I've also done it with simple for loop but does not work.

Comment: Do you want parallel executions of the queries or wait for the end of each query before executing the next one ?

Comment: I want to wait for each query to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to call `next()` after getting the result of the query:

```
var data = [];
var i = 0;
var j = 9;

async.whilst(
    function () { return i <= j; },
    function (next) {
        i++;

        connection.query('select * from table', function(err, rows, field) {
            data.push(rows.length);
            console.log(data);
            next();
        });
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution with `async`/`await` if you use [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=false&loose=true&spec=false&code=%28async%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20[]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20j%20%3D%209%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20%28i%20%3C%3D%20j%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20length%20%3D%20await%20new%20Promise%28%28resolve%2C%20reject%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20connection.query%28%27select%20*%20from%20table%27%2C%20function%28err%2C%20rows%2C%20field%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28err%29%20return%20reject%28err%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%28rows.length%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data.push%28length%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28data%29%3B%0A%7D%29%28%29):

```
(async function() {
    let data = [];
    let i = 0;
    const j = 9;

    while (i <= j) {
        let length = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query('select * from table', function(err, rows, field) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                resolve(rows.length);
            });
        });

        data.push(length);
    }

    return data;
})()
```